# How to back accidentially removed file in git repo?

Tags: git

```
 On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    web/img/add-btn-bg.png
#       deleted:    web/img/add-tribute-button.png
#       deleted:    web/img/bottom-shadow.png
#       deleted:    web/img/database-line.png
#       deleted:    web/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
#       deleted:    web/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
#       deleted:    web/img/header-logo.png
#       deleted:    web/img/horizontal-line.png
#       deleted:    web/img/icons-btn.png
#       deleted:    web/img/icons.png
#       deleted:    web/img/line-bottom-menu.png
#       deleted:    web/img/never-forget.png
#       deleted:    web/img/tribute-icon-line.png
#       deleted:    web/img/uszatek.jpg
#       deleted:    web/img/uszatek_106.jpg
#       deleted:    web/img/uszatek_148.jpg
#       deleted:    web/img/uszatek_32.jpg
#       deleted:    web/img/uszatek_50.jpg
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   web/app_dev.php
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       img/
#       randomNames.csv
#       sampledb.tgz
#       watch/
#       web/assets/
#       web/uploads/
```

I need have back file from "Changes to be commited". How to do it?

Comment: Did you actually read what you posted? Git is telling you exactly what you need to do: **`(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)`** followed by **`(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)`**.

Comment: I know, but I wrote "git reset HEAD web/img/*" and it didn't work so I thought I had to do something else. Sorry..

Comment: If you've already removed `web/img/*`, running `git reset HEAD web/img/*` won't do anything, because the shell attempts to expand `web/img/*` before calling `git`, fails, and so passes the literal string `web/img/*`, which `git` will try to match to a literal file name. It's a pain, but you'll have to run `git reset HEAD web/imgadd-btn-bg.png` and so on for each individual file (or parse the `git status` to generate the list of files (something like `git reset HEAD $(git status | awk '/deleted:/ { print $NF }')` (not tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't yet committed, here's how to get a file back (using `web/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png` as an example):

```
git reset HEAD web/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
git checkout -f web/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
```

This will unstage the remove operation, and then restore the file.

Comment: Thanks for answer... but I tell why didn't "git reset HEAD web/img/*" work to me?

Comment: The reason that didn't work is because "*" is evaluated by bash, not git. Since there's nothing to expand (you deleted the files), bash just passes that straight in to git. And git doesn't do wildcard expansion.